# Retrieve just one value using RetrieveSalesforceObjects

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

As the RetrieveSalesforceObjects AMPScript function retrieves a rowset of data, is there a way to retrieve just a single record?

For example, if some records match the criteria, only retrieve the first one that matches or one randomly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining the RetrieveSalesforceObject and the Row ampscript calls.

E.g

```
%%[ var @rs  @rowset
Set @rowset=RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'region', '=', 'west')
Set @rs=(Row(@rowset),1)
]%%

%%=@rs=%%
```

### Reference:

- [Row](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm)
- [RetrieveSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)

Comment: In what degree do you think the performance can be affected once you send the email and for each subscriber that call has to be executed? (let's say for a couple of thousands of subscribers)

Comment: I dont have a precise answer, but i suppose the biggest hit would come from the `RetrieveSalesforceObject` call since its an external API. The `Row` function would would be a wrapper to process data within SFMC so the incremental cost should be negligble. You might want to run tests with and without `Row` if its that important to your requirements.

Comment: RetrieveSalesforceObject does not stack up well in terms of performance. I have seen it take around 3 seconds for one iteration, row() doesn't really have a noticeable effect. Definitely load test such a solution. It probably will not be very fast.
You would be better off synchronising the data through data stream into a data extension and using AMPScript Lookups (lookupRows or lookupOrderedRows, again in combination with row() and field() ) instead of the external API.

Here is a good starting point for those methods: https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/